# Get float number that follows a label with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following text:

```
Total:                 192.5ms +/- 4.3%
```

I want to get the float `192.5`, `Total` label occurs only once so I can use this: `Total:\s+[0-9.]+` regular expression to get

```
Total:                 192.5
```

And then split on `:` and get `192.5`

I want to get directly the `192.5` float number in one regular expression. What regular expression do I need to get that directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#bodytext):

```
Total:\s+([0-9.]+)
```

and grab group 1.

---

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = 'Total:                 192.5ms +/- 4.3%'
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'Total:\s+([0-9.]+)', s).group(1)
'192.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

`192.5` is the first number string; Search for the number string, then use [`group()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) to get that string.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', 'Total:                 192.5ms +/- 4.3%').group()
'192.5'
```

or using [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', 'Total:                 192.5ms +/- 4.3%')
['192.5', '4.3']
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', 'Total:                 192.5ms +/- 4.3%')[0]
'192.5'
```

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu, What mean `that`? (I'm not good at English).

Comment: I meant +1 for expanding on `that answer` and providing the `findall` solution, I am not a native speaker either.